# Next Auth with Zitadel cloud: expected 200 OK, got: 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: next.js, next-auth

Using next.js, next-auth with zitadel

```
import ZitadelProvider from "next-auth/providers/zitadel";
...
providers: [
  ZitadelProvider({
    issuer: process.env.ZITADEL_ISSUER,
    clientId: process.env.ZITADEL_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.ZITADEL_CLIENT_SECRET,
  })
]
...
```

And .env

```
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=random
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000

# Next Auth ZITADEL Provider
ZITADEL_CLIENT_ID=xyz@myproject
ZITADEL_CLIENT_SECRET=random
ZITADEL_ISSUER=https://myinstance-qz4usg.zitadel.cloud/
```

I get the following error when I try to sign in with zitadel

```
[next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error expected 200 OK, got: 301 Moved Permanently {
  error: {
    message: 'expected 200 OK, got: 301 Moved Permanently',
    stack: 'OPError: expected 200 OK, got: 301 Moved Permanently\n' +
      '    at processResponse (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/process_response.js:41:11)\n' +
      '    at Function.discover (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/openid-client/lib/issuer.js:152:20)\n' +
      '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n' +
      '    at async openidClient (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client.js:16:14)\n' +
      '    at async getAuthorizationUrl (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/authorization-url.js:67:18)\n' +
      '    at async Object.signin (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/signin.js:38:24)\n' +
      '    at async AuthHandler (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:253:26)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuthHandler (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:23:19)\n' +
      '    at async /Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:59:32\n' +
      '    at async Object.apiResolver (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:363:9)\n' +
      '    at async DevServer.runApi (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:487:9)\n' +
      '    at async Object.fn (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:749:37)\n' +
      '    at async Router.execute (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:253:36)\n' +
      '    at async DevServer.run (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:384:29)\n' +
      '    at async DevServer.run (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:741:20)\n' +
      '    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/Users/sdoxsee/workspace/simplestep/my-t3-app/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:322:20)',
    name: 'OPError'
  },
  providerId: 'zitadel',
  message: 'expected 200 OK, got: 301 Moved Permanently'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying the issuer url from the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint put a trailing '/' at the end of my issuer (as can be seen in my .env above).

Removing the '/' fixed it.

i.e. `ZITADEL_ISSUER=https://myinstance-qz4usg.zitadel.cloud`